# How to use Fred's ImageMagick textcleaner script?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to do OCR on some of my images, but images are not quite very impressive. So, for cleaning it I wanted to use Fred's ImageMagick Textcleaner script. Command that I gave:-

```
sh textcleaner.sh input_file output_file -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 20 -t 30 -u -s 1 -T -p 20
```

This is the arguments which Fred has given on website itself. I am also doing for same sample image. But I don't think so any of my options are working everything is by default. And I keep getting this error also

```
textcleaner.sh: line 177: type: textcleaner.sh: not found
usage: dirname path
usage: basename string [suffix]
       basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]
```

And At last I had to keep the files in same folder where my textcleaner script is. How can I make it global and give the absolute path to it rather than putting the files wherever textcleaner is.

Answer (score 9):

It's a `bash` script - it says so in the first line - yet you are trying to run it in `sh` - which is not `bash`. You need to make the script executable, by running

```
chmod +x textcleaner
```

then you can run it properly using:

```
./textcleaner ... arguments ...
```

That should make the error message go away. Then try showing us a sample image so we can try and see what the problem is.

Comment: Please define *"not working"* - are there error messages still? Show us your image. Tell us your OS and IM version....

Comment: See my Pointers for Use at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Answer (score 3):

In my ImageMagick scripts, the syntax is script name ...arguments... input output. So your command should be

```
bash textcleaner.sh -g -e stretch -f 25 -o 20 -t 30 -u -s 1 -T -p 20 input_file output_file
```

See my Pointers For Use (for further configuration) at my home page: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: Would you mind telling me about which formats can be used for the output file or is the script kind of agnostic to that somehow? I can't find anything related to that within the script code and I'm randomly trying .tiff and .jpeg just to see if that affects it.

Comment: You can output any (raster) image format that Imagemagick supports. It all depends upon the suffix you use for the output image. Similarly for the input image. Vector formats such as PDF may not produce the results you want.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the case. First transform from pdf to something then edditing. Thanks, I wasn't completely sure.

Comment: I tried the same command but I have the following error `--- FILE input.jpg NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE ---` Could it be `.jpg` not supported? I also tried with `sudo` and `.png`. Regards

Comment: JPG is fine for input. Possibly you need to provide the path to your input and output images. Note that my script does not run on Windows. It is a bash Unix shell script. Use bash not sh. Be sure to run the script in a bash shell window. Be sure you read my Pointers for use, especially make the script executable.